# scala concepts involved in db withSession { implicit session =>

Tags: scala, slick

I am working in scala. I went through maximum all the concepts like high ordered function, curried functions, macros etc. But while working with slick i didn't understand this code snippet. `db withSession { implicit session =>`

What I understood is `JdbcBackend.DatabaseDef` is calling `withSession` method. So after that I dont know what is happening in that implementation. Please guys let me know or do I need to know even concepts related to this implementation. Tq

Comment: That's rather a loan pattern: https://blog.knoldus.com/2012/11/16/scalaknol-understanding-loan-pattern/

Comment: Thank you simpadjo

Answer (score 1):

You already seem to know the concepts. `withSession` is a function defined on `db` that takes a single function as it's argument, i.e. Higher-order function: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions.html.html

Scala will allow you to omit the dots when calling that function, i.e. Infix notation: https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#infix-notation

The curly brackets just create a standard code block, but as you're using `=>` you end up with a block that defines a function that is then passed to `withSession` as single argument using the infix notation.

Answer (score 0):

`withSession` method separates business logic from resource management logic. `db.withSession` provides a connection to the database to a user, then a user can use it, and after the body of `withSession` block is finished (normally or exceptionally) this connection is returned to the connection pool.

This approach is similar to java's `tryWithResource` idiom.

Comment: Thank you, Is "implicit session =>" is anonymous function from withSession method? or from any other resources.